# SQL Server: Split, Filter and Recombine

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, split, group-by

I want to Group By ContactID, and only recombine groups that have a Distinct Count of AutoNumber > 1. Using Pandas, I would do something like:

```
refinance_data = refinance_data.groupby('ContactID').filter(lambda x: x.AutoNumber.nunique() > 1)
```

My SQL query...

```
SELECT Ge.LoanAgreementID, Ge.Amount, Ge.ContactID, Ge.TransactionDate, Lo.AutoNumber, Ge.GeneralLedgerType FROM GeneralLedger as Ge
JOIN LoanAgreements Lo ON Ge.LoanAgreementID = Lo.LoanAgreementID
GROUP BY Ge.ContactID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Lo.AutoNumber) >1;
```

is producing the following error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'GeneralLedger.LoanAgreementID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Please provide the CREATE script and INSERT some sample data, we will be happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

May be this? (If I understand your explanation correctly.) I do not know panda.

```
SELECT Ge.LoanAgreementID, Ge.Amount, Ge.ContactID, Ge.TransactionDate, Lo.AutoNumber, GeneralLedgerType GETBND
FROM GeneralLedger AS Ge
JOIN LoanAgreements Lo ON Ge.LoanAgreementID = Lo.LoanAgreementID
WHERE
    Ge.ContactID IN (
SELECT Ge1.ContactID
FROM GeneralLedger AS Ge1
JOIN LoanAgreements Lo1 ON Ge1.LoanAgreementID = Lo1.LoanAgreementID
GROUP BY Ge1.ContactID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Lo1.AutoNumber) >1
)
```

Comment: Yes - this is perfect and exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could just join on the contactId:

```
SELECT Ge.LoanAgreementID, Ge.Amount, Ge.ContactID, Ge.TransactionDate, Lo.AutoNumber, Ge.GeneralLedgerType
FROM GeneralLedger as Ge
INNER JOIN 
 (
    SELECT Ge.ContactID
    FROM GeneralLedger as Ge
    JOIN LoanAgreements Lo ON Ge.LoanAgreementID = Lo.LoanAgreementID
    GROUP BY Ge.ContactID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Lo.AutoNumber) >1
    ) t
ON Ge.ContactID = t.ContactID;
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all where more than one distinct `AutoNumber` exists for `LoanAgreementID`:

```
select 
   Ge.LoanAgreementID
 , Ge.Amount
 , Ge.ContactID
 , Ge.TransactionDate
 , Lo.AutoNumber
 , Ge.GeneralLedgerType
from GeneralLedger as Ge
  inner join LoanAgreements Lo 
    on Ge.LoanAgreementID = Lo.LoanAgreementID
where exists (
  select 1 
  from LoanAgreements as i
  where i.LoanAgreementID = Lo.LoanAgreementID
    and i.AutoNumber != Lo.AutoNumber
)
```